# Please add -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch to code blocks and other overflown elements

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, design

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` is an iOS-specific CSS feature that enables native momentum-based scrolling on overflown elements.

Without it, scrolling just feels bad on iOS devices. Those who browse SO on an iPhone, iPod or iPad might relate to this.

Please add this CSS declaration to code blocks and other elements that can become overflown for a better user experience!

Comment: Please do. I will definitely bounty this if it doesn't get an official response.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Could you bounty this please? I don't have much rep to spare and this question is inactive for 3 days already.

Comment: done, lets get this fixed!

Comment: IMHO "let's get this fixed" should mean "make the iOS browser do the sane thing by default and not require properietary CSS to make it work". Out of curiosity: doesn't it allow scrolling *at all* without this, or does it just "not do it right"?

Comment: @JoachimSauer We can scroll them, yes, but without this property there's no momentum and no visible scrollbars. IMO it's an understandable design choice since `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` lets us scroll freely and only calls the scrolling event after we release the touch, which could cause flickering in many non-touch optmized javascript rich websites.

Comment: In [this video](http://youtu.be/KwpZ1F6dW5U) you can see the issue in the *lorem ipsum* box. No momentum, no scrollbars. Code blocks in SO suffer the same issue.